# Plotting GeoTIFF using Cartopy

Tags: python, sar, cartopy

I am trying to plot a SAR image, in TIFF format and containing the following projection arguments, using Cartopy.

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 / EPSG Norway Polar Stereographic",
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
PROJECTION["Polar_Stereographic"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",90],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",18],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.994],
PARAMETER["false_easting",2000000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",2000000],
UNIT["metre",1,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
AXIS["Easting",SOUTH],
AXIS["Northing",SOUTH],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","5939"]]
```

However, the image is not placed at the right location. I believe the error is related to how I define my projection. Does anyone have a tip? The Python script and SAR data can be found at: https://filesender.uninett.no/?s=download&token=7021f57f-d684-4fc3-89ca-6a2038f41230

Answer (score 1):

For those interested, I managed to use the arguments in the Cartopy Stereographic projection, like:

```
projection = ccrs.Stereographic(central_latitude=90, central_longitude=18, \
false_easting=2000000, false_northing=2000000, true_scale_latitude=90, globe=None)
```

It seems to have worked, but I will leave this question open in case someone comes with a different solution.